# XAMPP: setting the encoding type globally

Tags: php, encoding, xampp

When I run a csv parser on my windows machine, and redirect the output into a file, I always get doubled up line breaks when I open the file in OpenOffice Calc. Further, if I copy the contents of the file in notepad++, then save that as a new file using the default ANSI encoding, the file is half as big and line breaks display properly in Calc.

I'd prefer not to have to add a setting or header to every file I work on, since these scripts work fine on a linux install of PHP.

I assume that changing a setting in php.ini will fix this, but I don't know what it is and I haven't had much luck finding it. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I fear no such setting exists, but I'll take a look.

Comment: How are you creating the CSV file to begin with? I would guess that you need to force a single "\n" at the end of each line, vs "\r\n" that Windows installs would do be default. I didn't think that fputcsv() uses "\r\n", so it's odd that they are (seemingly) there...

Comment: @Narcissus not using fputcsv, just building a string using implode("\t", $whatever) . "\n"

Comment: @user973810: so the 'parser' is actually a creator? Or are you parsing a CSV file and converting it to a tab delimited file? I'm not quite sure where the 'double new lines' are coming from but if it's a UTF-8 thing then wouldn't you only need to set it to ASCII in the one script that is creating the CSV?

Comment: Could you add code for where your parser writes to file, and relevant processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [an INI directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) to change the character set sent by default in the `Content-Type` header:

Per example:

```
default_charset = "iso-8859-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh? You want to create a text file that opens correctly in both windows and linux?

Tough luck. Both operating system uses different ways to denote new lines. One uses a new line, where else the other ses a new line and a carrage return.

In Linux, there are programs called "dos2unix" and "unix2dos" that converts text for you between the windows and linux world. I think you will need to use that everytime you copy the files between the operating systems.

Comment: That's not the problem at all. My XAMPP is defaulting everything to UTF output. I don't care about new lines, I can control that within the script.