# How to fix mistake language when get value from ajax to web on xampp

Tags: php, ajax, xampp

When I  change the server from Appserve to xampp, it has a problem with the thai language. When I send and get a value using ajax it's returned incorrectly, like ������ ��. But I set `"meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-874"` in the head tag on my web page, and I changed `$cfg['Lang'] = '';` to `$cfg['Lang'] = 'tis-620';` in the file config.inc.php
But if it runs on Appserve, it works. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why windows 874 ?

I mean, usually you use

```
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
```

That should solve the problem.

**Update**

Understood, so you may want to add to your ajax :

```
contentType:"application/x-javascript; charset:windows-874"
```

If that doesnt work a header in your php file would help too

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-874');
```

You can try also, sending the values from the server in URL format with

```
urlencode(myJson);//php function
```

then with javascript retrieve it with

```
decodeURIComponent(TheResponse);//js Function
```

I hope it helps

Comment: In my Database SQL server  set  "Collation = Thai_100_CI_AS". Then when I select data to web page I must to set <meta charset="windows-874">. plase help thank you

Comment: It' s work!! Thank you. but you have any way to fix this problem such as config file or change setting something in xampp. Because if I use this solution. I must edit every files and it has many many files to do. Then You have a any way to do this?  thx

Comment: Mmm not actually, I wouldn't recommend it , but you can checkout this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/8014043/4241030 It modifies a directive of the php.ini